# Does "Binding" mechanism make it unnecessary to use MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, binding

According to MVC pattern:

- events raised in View are intercepted in Controller, which updates the Model.
- events raised in Model, are intercepted in View, which updates itself.

But all mentioned above can be done by simple binding. This mechanism allows to update View when model is changed and update Model if the View is changed.

Am I right or there is something I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the view to a model is not MVC pattern (maybe you could call it "MV", because you only have the model and the view). The crucial part of the MVC pattern is the controller. And in a slightly complex application that does more than just displaying data you need a controller that does execute application logic. For example if a user clicks a button and you want to load another view.

If you work with the MVC pattern your application logic will reside in the controller and not directly execute by the button click as this allows a separation of view and application logic.